# Microservices with App Engine and API Gateway

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have several microservices hosted using GAE Stadard. Currently the UI communicates directly with each service. I'd like to setup an API gateway so the traffic will be routed to the correct service based on path. E.g. any requests starts with /products will go to service A, while /orders will go to service B.

Is it something can be done using Google Cloud, without having to develop a new routing service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a New Feature in Beta for App Engine that allow you to setup and deploy an API gateway for your services, which is exactly what you want to do.

You can check details and a tasklist of how to set it up in this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-app-engine).